# What is the integral of this summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, fourier-series

What is the integral of $$\int_0^1 e^{-2 \pi jix} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty u_ke^{2 \pi kix}  $$
where j,k are integers, i imaginary, and $$u_k$$ in complex numbers, known as Fourier coefficients

Comment: Push $e^{-2 \pi jix} $ inside the summation to have:
$\int_0^1  \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty u_ke^{2 \pi (k-j)ix}\,dx= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \int_0^1 u_ke^{2 \pi (k-j)ix}\,dx $ which is easy to evaluate

Comment: exchanging the integral and summation signs depends on the norm of $u_k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions are orthonormal, and you can pull the constants out of the integral. The answer is $u_{j}$.

This obviously is only valid under some conditions on the convergence of the series of Fourier coefficients.

$$\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi i j x} \sum_k u_k e^{2\pi i k x} dx =\sum_k u_k \int_0^1 e^{-2\pi i j x}  e^{2\pi i k x} dx $$
$$=\sum_k u_k\, \left\langle e^{2 \pi i k x},e^{2\pi i j x}\right\rangle=u_j.$$

Comment: The answer is actually $$u_j$$ This might seem silly but how do I pull the constants out of the integral.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Should have just trusted my first post. I'll update to show the work.

Comment: I don't really understand the last line, where has the inequality come from?

Comment: That's an inner product on $L^2((0,1))$, not an inequality. If you haven't shown the integral is $1$ when $k=j$ and $0$ otherwise yet, evaluate it by hand.

Comment: Ah, I see thank you for your help.